# After upgrading flutter to 1.20 textfield gives error on lower Android API devices

Tags: android, flutter, dart, textfield

```
final textController = TextEditingController();

TextField(
  controller:textController,
  decoration:InputDecoration(...)
)
```

Error log:

```
W/System.err( 8349): java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.content.ClipData.getItemCount()' on a null object reference
W/System.err( 8349): at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1626) 
W/System.err( 8349): at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1573) 
W/System.err( 8349): at android.content.IClipboard$Stub$Proxy.getPrimaryClip(IClipboard.java:197) 
W/System.err( 8349): at android.content.ClipboardManager.getPrimaryClip(ClipboardManager.java:258) 
W/System.err( 8349): at io.flutter.plugin.platform.PlatformPlugin.getClipboardData(PlatformPlugin.java:274)
```

On lower Android API devices, it is giving me an error. I am using a Samsung j7 having Android 6. Help me out.

Comment: Change your android device version to 21

Comment: It is already 21.

Comment: I think no one can answer this question.It's been 5 days since I posted this question.